# Define custom navigation paths in Google Maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsgroundoverlay

I am trying to implement something like Google's indoor maps feature, locally in my iOS app, using GroundOverlays. I could easily get the overlay part done by overlaying a .png image at some position in the map, using the API. I could also implement a custom floors switcher, just like Google's one, so it changes the floor overlay image. However, I still miss the ability to navigate in the native indoor maps. How can I define custom navigation paths in that region so when user navigates between two points inside it, the calculated path gets generated with respecting them?

Comment: The best way to do it might be submitting an actual indoor floor plan? https://maps.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/

Comment: The problem is that we need to support offline mode for the indoor maps. As I read, implementing a real offline mode through the API violates Google Maps SDK ToS.

Comment: Maybe have a look into the open source alternative GraphHopper https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios using OpenStreetMap data

Comment: @Karussell How does that help me? Can I add custom routes through API? I didn't find such thing in the documentations.